# Unexplained Spike in RDS replica lag

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, replication, lag, read-replication

We have a RDS read-replica server. We found some spike in replica lag as shown below:

[Click here to see the observed replica lag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXAuD.png)

However, when we checked the general log we did not find any insert,delete,optimize or alter commands. Can anyone explain what is going on ?

Comment: If it's a single-AZ instance, I would guess AWS is creating an automated snapshot.